# Java Key Down fast clicking

Tags: java, gwt, key

I have a small question. But lets start from code:

```
@Override
protected void onKeyDown(NativeEvent e) {
  count ++;
  System.out.println(count);
}
```

So as you see I holding key down on my keyboard, and printing variable immediately. After some while `count` gets `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

OUTPUT (after spamming on key):

```
21
22
23
24
..
2147483647
```

My question - is that of fast clicking of DOWN key? and how I can manage to overcome this nonsense. Thanks for help.

---

EDITED

Im thinking to use `Timer` class.

---

EDITED

Noticed that this bug appears just for **down arrow key** , everything looks good for up key.

Comment: `onKeyUp` is for arrow which goes up , i need to use `onKeyDown` for arrow which goes down

Comment: Which framework are you using ? It sounds like GWT.

Comment: GWT framework, is that matters?

Comment: @J.Doe It seems that you are going to implement something like game, aren't?

Comment: Yes something like that

Answer (score 0):

When you want to add a `keydown` listener to a container, then when you `keydown` on that container it will fire the event in high speed, as you say the `count ++;` dramatically gets `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so if you prevent this problem, you can use `Thread.sleep` almost about `20ms` and so on... then it will work good.

**Edit:**

```
private boolean isDown;
public void onKeyDown(Event event) {
    isDown = true;
    new Thread(new MyThread()).start();
}

public void onKeyUp(Event event) {
    isDown = false;
}

private class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        while (isDown) {
            // do your work
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it can help you!

Comment: And it should look like this : ? `protected void onKeyDown(NativeEvent e) {
  count ++;
  Thread.sleep(20);
  System.out.println(count);
}` @Bahramdun Adil

Comment: [link]https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/LnavJoe47No/n5iUzW-q8asJ   , also tried with Timer. Useless

Comment: @J.Doe Yes something like that.

Comment: I posted a comment, that says it is impossible to use Thread in GWT framework

Comment: Why you don't, you can create thread to do the thins that you want when the key has been pressed, but when you want to refresh UI or change UI, you can do in main thread (UI thread).

Comment: The answer updated, you can look and try something like that, hope to be useful for you!

Comment: **No source code is available for type java.lang.Thread; did you forget to inherit a required module?** on line - `new Thread(new MyThread()).start();`